# Make a matrix of matrices

Tags: julia

I want to have a matrix whose elements are matrices too.

For example

```
A=[[1 2 3;3 4 1;2 3 6]  [1 4 5;4 8 7;2 0 1];[1 5 8;6 4 7;2 0 0]  [2 1 5;4 7 7;2 4 6]]
```

How can I make this matrix in Julia?

Comment: Hi, I see you're relatively new to SO. Did you find an answer to your question? If any answer solved your question you can consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark next to it. This helps keep the focus on questions which still don't have answers. You might also want to check your other two questions in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = first.([([1 2 3;3 4 1;2 3 6],) ([1 4 5;4 8 7;2 0 1],);
            ([1 5 8;6 4 7;2 0 0],) ([2 1 5;4 7 7;2 4 6],)])
```

works (on Julia 0.6). Making elements tuples stops the fusing of the submatrices and then `first.` untuples them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a shorthand / literal, but you can construct it and then populate it:

```
B=Matrix{Matrix}(3,3)
Out[4]:
3×3 Array{Array{T,2} where T,2}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef
B[1,1]=[1 2 ; 3 4]
B
Out[8]:
3×3 Array{Array{T,2} where T,2}:
    [1 2; 3 4]  #undef  #undef
 #undef         #undef  #undef
 #undef         #undef  #undef
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Julia has this (from my POV strange) property:

```
julia> [1 2 [3 4]]
1×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4
```

But we could use it to make this trick:

```
julia> A=[[[1 2 3;3 4 1;2 3 6]] [[1 4 5;4 8 7;2 0 1]];
          [[1 5 8;6 4 7;2 0 0]] [[2 1 5;4 7 7;2 4 6]]]
```

Another strange possibility is (be aware that it is visually transposed!):

```
julia> A=hcat([[1 2 3;3 4 1;2 3 6], [2 1 5;4 7 7;2 4 6]], 
              [[1 4 5;4 8 7;2 0 1], [1 5 8;6 4 7;2 0 0]])
```

or (this needs to be visually transposed too!)

```
julia> A=reshape([[1 2 3;3 4 1;2 3 6], [2 1 5;4 7 7;2 4 6], 
                  [1 4 5;4 8 7;2 0 1], [1 5 8;6 4 7;2 0 0],], 
                 (2,2))
```

**Edit:**
Ad your additional question - you could create Array of desired length and then use reshape:

```
U = reshape(Matrix{Float64}[zeros(8, 5) for i in 1:20*20], (20,20));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty matrix of the aformentioned dimensions first by :

```
X = zeros(Int64, (3, 3,4))
```

You can further assign each matrix accordingly:

```
X[:,:,1] = [1 2 3;3 4 1;2 3 6]
X[:,:,2] = [1 4 5;4 8 7;2 0 1]
X[:,:,3] = [1 5 8;6 4 7;2 0 0]
X[:,:,4] = [2 1 5;4 7 7;2 4 6]
```

And the matrix X is :

```
julia > X
julia > 3×3×4 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
1  2  3
3  4  1
2  3  6

[:, :, 2] =
1  4  5
4  8  7
2  0  1

[:, :, 3] =
1  5  8
6  4  7
2  0  0

[:, :, 4] =
2  1  5
4  7  7
2  4  6
```

An easier thing to do is to read every element as is by a vector and reshape it.

```
x = [1,2,3,3,4,1,2,3,6,1,4,5,4,8,7,2,0,1,1,5,8,6,4,7,2,0,0,2,1,5,4,7,7,2,4,6]
x = reshape(x, (3, 3, 4))
```

This will result in 4 matrices that need a transpose, so for that you can use the permutedims as folows to change the order of the first and second dimensions(each matrix):

```
 permutedims(x,(2,1,3))
```